# Single Apostrophe Parse issues ASP CLASSIC

Tags: php, string, excel, asp-classic

I have users uploading data from an excel file to my server, parsed, and then displayed on my website. I have an issue where if the user has a single apostrophe in the excel file it will cut off everything after it. This is because both sql(used to grab the excel data) and the asp classic code(used to display dynamic html data) are interpreting this as a field delimiter. I used php to process the excel file and replace the apostrophe with whatever character I desire. I attempted to use escape versions of apostrophe to no avail "\'", "''","\'\'", "'". This is because even the though they fix the issue with the sql grabbing the data properly, the ASP code continues to cut off characters before it can be displayed. I ended up using "**" as the replacement for apostrophe to get past the sql, but must convert it back to an apostrophe before it is outputted for the user by the ASP:

```
formString= formString & "<tr>" & _"<td align='left'><input name='FirstName' type='text' size='9' maxlength='12' value='"&replace(someUglyString,"**","&#39;")&"'></td>"
```

Has anyone come across this? any ideas?

php as requested:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow(); $i++) {
$cell = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow('A', $i);
$cell->setValue(str_replace("'","**",$cell->getValue()));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow('A',$i,$cell->getValue());
```

}

Comment: Sorry, why are you mixing ASP and PHP? Can't you just pick a language and stick to it? Also please show us the PHP code you use to process the file into the database, as this is where the real problem lies.

Comment: the php works fine, it replaces what I tell it to. just the asp outputting the field later on is  what is having the issue. the php reads in the excel file and converts the apostrophes in the field to what I desire and then re-saves it on the server.

Comment: My point is that the "replace with a random string" approach is the wrong one - you should simply be escaping the input so that the raw data is correctly entered into the database.

Comment: I agree with you except for the word "simply" bc I could not figure out any other way. What the user enters into the excel file is outside of my control. I need to pre-process in some way before the excel data is read from the excel by "SELECT * FROM A1:Q10000;" I can escape with double single apostrophe '' using the php but later on the ASP still takes issue w/ all methods of escape that I could imagine

Comment: If you want to stuff random text into an attribute value, there's no escaping (ha!) having to escape certain values in that text. You just need to pick a method that works for you. You could always double-quote your "value" attribute, but then you'd have to escape anf double-quotes in the submitted text...

Comment: @DaveRandom - ASP is a framework, not a language: it works fine with (egs.) vbscript, javascript, Python, PHP or Perl.

Comment: I like your idea bc I want to treat " as invalid later on anyway (whereas apostrophes are later valid). I'll use the php to strip double quotes from the excel input to begin with and do the single qoute escape to get past the sql and then convert the escape back into a single quote.

Comment: but its interpreting single quotes as a comment... rather than a string

Comment: @JonathanDavis Could you use Chr(39) instead of the literal single quote?  This question is taking me back years to my ASP classic days and I remember the single quote was sometimes a nightmare because it doubles as the token for commenting out a line.   I can't remember my solution! Or was the solution to emit 2 apostrophes in order to display 1 apostrophe?

Comment: I did try using "chr(39)" and it gave me the same issue as if I just had a single quote- cutting off the rest of the field. double apostrophe didn't do it either, it would see the first one and just cut off the rest of the field. although this isn't a huge issue as no users have complained about it- it has been an annoying one lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

&apos did it. I'm really surprised that I couldn't find this anywhere.